# How to combine a Spring Data MongoDB Query with full text search?

Tags: spring, search, full-text-search, spring-data-mongodb

I've recently upgraded to Spring Data MongoDB 1.6.0.RC1, which is very good and implements the full text search feature of MongoDB 2.6 (huuurah!). My question is: how can I combine the Criteria and TextCriteria classes to generate complex queries ?

Example object model:

```
{
  textProperty: "a text that is indexed for full text search",
  language:"en",
  aBooleanProperty: true,
  anIntegerProperty: 1
}
```

Query:

```
db.collection({ anIntegerProperty: 1,  $text: { $search: "indexed", $language: "en" } })
```

So, how can I write the above query with Spring Data MongoDB classes?

Answer (score 10):

Note: this post had non working code previously but is now fixed!

A `TextCriteria` is a `CriteriaDefinition` and thus can be used with a `Query` like this:

```
Quer query = Query.query(
  Criteria.where("aBooleanProperty").is(true).
  and(anIntegerProperty).is(1)).
  addCriteria(TextCriteria.
    forLanguage("en"). // effectively the same as forDefaultLanguage() here
    matching("a text that is indexed for full text search")));

List<YourDocumentType> result = mongoTemplate.findAll(query. YourDocumentType.class);
```

Polish this up by using static imports for `Query.query` and `Criteria.where` and it reads pretty fluent.

Comment: How did you manage to add TextCriteria to the query with 'and' operand? Because I can not do it now

Comment: This one does not work. TextCriteria is not the same object as Criteria

Comment: Hey everyone! Sorry for the confusion. I was writing the previous example down from the top of my head. I've fixed this now. The trick is to use `addCriteria(…)` on the query instead of `and(…)` on the `Criteria`.

Comment: Is TextSearch not applicable for number search ? If yes, what is the way to get the search for numbers? Please see the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163606/text-search-not-working-with-spring-boot-mongodb

Answer (score 4):

Spring data supports MongoDB full text search queries.
Consider in the below example, we are trying to search the text inside textProperty field. You need to add @TextIndexed annotation for the field you want to search.

Model object :

```
public class TextExample {

@Id
private String id;

private String textProperty;

@TextIndexed
private String language;

private String aBooleanProperty;

private int anIntegerProperty;
```

}

While constructing the TextCriteria you can provide the language option(I have considered a default language which is english)

Query :

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny(
            "en");

    Query query = TextQuery.queryText(criteria).sortByScore();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("anIntegerProperty").is(1));   

    List<TextExample> textExamples = mongoTemplate.find(query, TextExample.class);
```

This should return the matching records with the language as "en" and anIntegerProperty as 1.

Please refer to [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.6.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/text/class-use/TextCriteria.html) for the TextCriteria documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Building Query entity, you can combine criteria by using the method `Query.addCriteria()`, that accepts `CriteriaDefinition` parameter. Both `TextCriteria` and `Criteria` implement `CriteriaDefinition`.
For example, if you want to combine `TextCriteria` and `Criteria`, you can do it as follows:

```
// Create TextCriteria
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny("some key word"); 
// Build Query
Query query = TextQuery.queryText(criteria);
// Add the additional criteria to query
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("field").is("fieldValue"));
```

Comment: Is there any way we can use $near with it ?

Answer (score 1):

According to my research TextCriteria and Criteria there is no way to combine them using Spring Data MongoDB 1.6.2.RELEASE for aggregation (group by - aggregate feature).
I made this ugly hack for it:

```
private static class QueryHack extends Query implements CriteriaDefinition {
    @Override
    public DBObject getCriteriaObject() {
        return getQueryObject();
    }

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
QueryHack hack = new QueryHack();
hack.addCriteria(textCriteria).addCriteria(criteria);
MatchOperation match1 = new MatchOperation(hack); //Also it's not possible to use static method match(textCriteria) - it takes Criteria only.
```

I will add JIRA ticket to Spring MongoDB project.

Comment: Did you end up filing a JIRA ticket for this? I ended up using a variation of your trick to compose multiple `Criteria` and `TextCriteria` in an `Aggregation.match()`. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I think I forgot to do that. Please do it yourself. I don't use MongoDB anymore and you will probably able to describe details better.

Comment: Thanks, Vity. This still works in 2018!  Let us know if better approach exists using MatchOperation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a compound index with Spring Data MongoDB like this:

```java
@Document
@CompoundIndex(def = "{'anIntegerProperty': 1, 'textProperty': 'text'}")
```

Then create a Repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface TheDocuemntRepository extends MongoRepository<TheDocuemnt, String> {

    Stream<TheDocuemnt> findByAnIntegerPropertyOrderByScoreDesc(Integer anIntegerProperty, TextCriteria criteria);

}
```

Consider MongoDB documentation:

> **Compound Index**
>
> A compound index can include a text index key in combination with ascending/descending index keys. However, these compound indexes have the following restrictions:
>
> - A compound text index cannot include any other special index types, such as multi-key or geospatial index fields.
> - If the compound text index includes keys preceding the text index key, to perform a $text search, the query predicate must include equality match conditions on the preceding keys.

## Filter search results by language

If you also want to filter search results by language, you should try this approach: [Multi-language documents example](https://github.com/ciri-cuervo/spring-data-mongodb-multi-language)

#### The entity

```java
@CompoundIndex(def = "{'anIntegerProperty': 1, 'language': 1, 'textProperty': 'text'}")
```

#### The repository

```java
Sort TEXT_SCORE_SORT = new Sort(Direction.DESC, "score");

@Query("{'anIntegerProperty': ?0, 'language': ?1, $text: {$search: ?2, $language: ?1}}")
Stream<TheDocuemnt> findTheDocument(Integer property, String language, String criteria, Sort sort);
```